# File got corrupted and size is increased when uploading after publishing code on AWS Lambda function with .NET Core 3.1

Tags: amazon-web-services, .net-core, aws-lambda, asp.net-core-3.1

I'm Uploading mp3 file in aws s3 bucket, when i upload from my local system its working fine and uploading file with same size. but after publishing on AWS, when i try to upload file, file getting corrupted and also file size is increased.
Here is my API :
I'm just returning file from here.

```
[HttpPost, DisableRequestSizeLimit]
    [Route("SaveSoundRecordingDataFile")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> SaveSoundRecordingDataFile()
    {
        try
        {
            var file = Request.Form.Files[0];
            return Ok(file);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return StatusCode(500, $"Internal server error: {ex}");
        }
    }
```

Check below responses I'm uploading 1MB size file you will find how file size are getting increased after publish code on aws lambda.

Response from Local System :

[Response from local system](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zeOgt.png)

Response after publish on aws lambda :

[Response from aws](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T6B3n.png)

I have tried many ways and go through many articles and forms but didn't find any solution why is this happening.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Any chance that it's base64-encoded?

Comment: @jarmod its not encoded in any way. im just returning file as it is

Comment: I'm suggesting that you might have accidentally encoded it in base64 and you will be able to see that in the retrieved file. It would explain the different file content and the size increase.

Comment: @jarmod as i told its not encoded any where. do you have more suggestion on it, kindly have a deep look in my problem

Comment: If the file size and file content on S3 are different to what you think you uploaded then you are almost certainly mistaken in what you uploaded.

Comment: @jarmod i'm uploading same file. let me explain If i upload a .txt file then its not getting corrupted. when try to upload any media like mp3,image,etc  after published code on AWS then file's size get increased magically there is no affect on files when upload from local system.

Comment: All I'm saying is that the chance of S3 having a bug here is vanishingly small, and it is therefore almost certainly the case that what you think is happening is not what is actually happening. What does "publishing on AWS" mean here? It would help if you could clarify the process that is taking the file from its source (where presumably you have verified that the file content is correct) and to its final destination in S3 (where you claim it has changed size and become corrupted). Or is the file correct in S3 but appears corrupt after you download it (if so how are you downloading)?

Comment: And tell us how you know the file has become corrupted and is the wrong size. In some detail, preferably. What evidence do you have before and after, and how did you collect this evidence? Postman screenshots don't work here.

Comment: @AmanTiwari did you find any solution? I am facing same problem.